# Why the remote ls from here doc from ssh does not work within a $()?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-substitution, here-document

I am trying to count the number of files in a remote directory.
I have the following code:

```
ssh server.com<<RUNTHIS  
 FILE_COUNT=$(ls -AU /foo/bar/test_dir) 
 echo "$FILE_COUNT" > ~/file_count.txt   
RUNTHIS
```

When I run this I get: `ls: /foo/bar/test_dir No such file or directory`
**But** the directory is there. If I do `ls /foo/bar/test_dir` directly to the server it lists the directory.
Also the following works and saves the contents to the file:

```
ssh server.com<<RUNTHIS  
 ls -AU /foo/bar/test_dir > ~/file_count.txt
RUNTHIS
```

What is wrong in the first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `bash` will do parameter expansion and command substitution in the `heredoc`. Try with single quotes around `RUNTHIS` to protect it.

```
ssh server.com<<'RUNTHIS' 
 FILE_COUNT=$(ls -AU /foo/bar/test_dir) 
 echo "$FILE_COUNT" > ~/file_count.txt   
RUNTHIS
```

Comment: A less weird way to do this would be `ssh server.com "ls -AU" > ~/file_count.txt` (If I recall how to ssh correctly)

Comment: That won't work for me. I have other commands as part of that block that break if I add the single quote.

Comment: @Blacksilver: that doesn't do the same thing though, does it. (It writes the file locally and not remotely).

Comment: @Jim: Where does it break if you use single quotes? Could you give an example?

Comment: oh, do you want to write to a remote file? `ssh server.com "ls -AU > ~/file_count.txt"`

Comment: Yes, that does work for the example (changing the argument of `ls`). :)

Comment: @Rastapopoulos: It is mentioned even in the docs. I need all my commands in the snippet to run and some are quoted etc

Comment: What is mentioned? I don't see what the problem in the case of your example...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your $(ls) expands locally, rather than remotely.

Try this...

```
ssh -2 -4 -i $key root@$ip -- 'ls -AU /foo/bar/test_dir | wc -l > ~/file_count.txt'
```